# How to change the default color of validation message in knockoutJS

Tags: css, knockout-validation

> I have applied validation on HTML page through knockoutJS..when i suppose to click the submit button the validation works well but the message is displaying with black color...I want it to show with Red..Here is a small piece of my View page:

```
         <tr>
            <td align="right" style="width: 30%;">
                <b>Name :</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width: 70%;">
                <input data-bind="value: EmployeeName" placeholder="Employee Name" class="txt"
                    type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

> And My View Model (continued from the above):

```
var EmpViewModel = function () {


        //Make the self as 'this' reference
        var self = this;
        //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
        self.EmployeeCode = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please enter your Employee Code.'} }); //WANT TO CHANGE THIS MESSAGE TEXT COLOR TO RED..
        self.EmployeeName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please enter your Name.'} });
        self.Dob = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please enter your Date of Birth.'} });
        self.Age = ko.observable("").extend({ number: true, required: { message: 'Please enter your Age.'} });
        self.ContactNumber = ko.observable("").extend({ number: true, required: { message: 'Please enter your Contact Number.'} });
        self.EmailID = ko.observable("").extend({ email: true, required: { message: 'Please enter your EmailID.'} });
        self.Address = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please enter your Address.'} });
        self.MaritalStatus = ko.observable("");
        self.City = ko.observable("");
        self.Is_Reference = ko.observable("");

        //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
        var EmpData = {
            EmpCode: self.EmployeeCode,
            EmpName: self.EmployeeName,
            Dob: self.Dob,
            Age: self.Age,
            ContactNumber: self.ContactNumber,
            MaritalStatus: self.MaritalStatus,
            EmailID: self.EmailID,
            Address: self.Address,
            City: self.City,
            Is_Reference: self.Is_Reference
        };


        self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, observable: false });

        //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
        self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);

        //Function to perform POST (insert Employee) operation
        self.save = function () {
            // check if valid
            if (self.errors().length > 0) {
                self.errors.showAllMessages();
                return;
            }
            //Ajax call to Insert the Employee
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Exercise/Save/",
                data: ko.toJSON(this), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    window.close();
                    opener.location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
            //Ends Here
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new EmpViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom message template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="myCustomTemplate">
    <span 
         class="yourCustomCssClass" 
         data-bind="if: field.isModified() && !field.isValid(), 
                    text: field.error"></span>
</script>
```

And configure knockout-validation to use it:

```
ko.validation.init({ messageTemplate: 'myCustomTemplate' });
```

Or like described here: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Thanx delixfe...that works fine..bt is it possible that the validation message show only or after clicking on submit button...here is the scenario in jsFIDDLE...if you remembered this fiddle too made by you...http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/tSzYf/2/

Comment: My solution works like the standard message of knockout-validation. It shows a message if the observable is not valid AND it is modified. You can test that in the fiddle by entering a name, leaving the input field and removing the name again. On submit it marks all fields as changed. -> That could make another question because formatting is nto supported here..